# How to make JDBCTemplate.query() generic

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am new to spring framework.I found this even by looking in documentation but didn't find my desired method. 
Let me explain thing which I want 
`JDBCTemplate.query()` method can take multiple parameters which can be `2, 3 ,4....n`.Now I am trying to find a method [if `JDBTemplate` have] through which i just passed a object/array/list , mean a generic parameter so I get rid from the multiple methods.As If I have 200 stored procedures then I have to write 200 mehods! huh
Currently I am doing this by passing an array and splitting it at DB end but I want to find a good way.Any idea/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
   //set any number of parameters
   Object[] parameters = new Object[] { new Integer(1), "test" };
   String sqlQuery = "select * from table1 t where t.id = ? and t.text = ?";
   SqlRowSet srs = getJdbcTemplate().queryForRowSet(sqlQuery , parameters);
```

You may generalize the is by passing the `query` and `parameters` from outside of the method as an argument.